# Backing up Git Repositories

Tags: backup, git

At the moment our git repositories (hosted on an internal server) are being backed up when the entire Virtual Machine that they are sitting on gets backed up.

Is it enough to literally copy those files onto another area if I want another backup option or is there a better way to do it in git.

I am worried that if I just do a copy and paste there could be some information copied that makes the local branches of git spazz out if they try and commit to a restored repository.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dude, its GIT. `git clone ssh://myserver/path/to/git/repo.git`. But if you don't buy that, or you want to be particularly paranoid, grabbing the contents of the entire folder should work, as long as you catch the .git directory.

Comment: I didn't want to just take a clone of it somewhere else because then surely if the original repository gets deleted I have a whole load of clones not being able to talk to one place? Maybe I am over thinking it a bit.

Comment: +1 - Yep, Git isn't like Windows. It doesn't scatter information all over the place (registries, system directories, or any of that BS). *Everything* is in the `.git` directory. Copy that and you have a complete backup.

Comment: @Toby: There is nothing special about the repository on your server. Every clone is just as capable of being the "one place". All cloned repositories are equals (and all branches are equals, for that matter;  i.e. there is nothing special about `master`). If your server repository is a "bare" repo, you can recreate the bare repo from a non-bare clone, by using `git clone --bare`.